# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'JSON'

Tags: json, swift, completionhandler

Previously it's working well with `Swift 3`, But when I switch to `Swift 4`, Unable to find issue with completion with type `JSON(SwiftyJson Library)`

```
static func getRoster(information: [String: String], completion:@escaping ([Player],JSON,Paging?,WSResponse,NSError?) -> Void){
        Alamofire.request(NetWorkingConstants.baseURL+NetWorkingConstants.Team.get_all_roster, method: .post, parameters: information, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:StarsLeagueUser.sharedInstance.getDefaultHeaders()).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                let wsResponse = WSResponse(code: json["response_code"].stringValue, message: json["message"].stringValue)


                if wsResponse.code == ServerCode.success{
                    print("Success")

                }else if wsResponse.code == ServerCode.unauthorized{
                    print("Session Expire")
                }
            case .failure(let error):

               print("Network Error")
                let wsResponse = WSResponse(code: "1000", message: "Network Error")
                completion([],nil,nil,wsResponse,error as NSError?)//Here is error - Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'JSON'
                print("GetRoster")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: since in code you have written to expect the server response in json and if the response is not json you are getting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to ( `,JSON?` )

```
func getRoster(information: [String: String], 
 completion:@escaping ([Player],JSON?,Paging?,WSResponse,NSError?) -> Void){
```

As to be able to return a nil value , then it should be optional

Making the return type `JSON` as non-optional means that you have to return a non - optional value so returning nil is a problem like you do

```
var str1:String = nil // error 
var str2:String? = nil // ok
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working, Can you explain? Where I was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you cannot pass `nil` if the parameter type is non-optional. Declare `JSON` as optional (`JSON?`).

In your case I recommend to use an enum with associated types as result type.

The benefit is the parameters are better arranged and you have always non-optional types because you are returning only the relevant parameters

```
enum Result {
   case success([Player], JSON, Paging, WSResponse)
   case failure(WSResponse, Error)
}
```

Then declare your method

```
func getRoster(information: [String: String], completion:@escaping (Result) -> Void) {
```

and return in the failure case

```
let wsResponse = WSResponse(code: "1000", message: "Network Error")
completion(.failure(wsResponse, error))
```

In the caller method use a `switch`

```
switch result {
    case let .success(players, json, paging, response):
    // handle success
    case let .failure(response, error):
    // handle error
}
```